# socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided when using socket

Tags: python

I'm writing a little portscan program and when I run I get this following error:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not
>   known.

I've found a few posts where the same error was being discussed but this was all related to other modules. I have tried and experimented so i know where the error comes from.

What I tried:

- The code below works when I pick a specific entry by writing e.g. hosts_ip[1]
- I have found out that when I use `socket.gethostbyname()` and input for example a domain name Ill get the IP of that host.
- The code works when I replace host_ip (where the error is) by an IP in quotes, e.g. `127.0.0.1`.

Why won't code below work with entries from a file? Am I doing something wrong with loading in / reading the file? Thanks in advance, really curious what the problem is here.

```
import os
import subprocess
import socket
import sys

def load_hosts():
    file = open('hosts.txt', 'r')
    hosts = file.readlines()
    return hosts

def portscan():
    hosts = load_hosts()
    port = 80
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(4)
    for host_ip in hosts:
        result = sock.connect_ex((host_ip, port)) #Error is here
    if result == 0:
        print('[*] Port is open')
    else:
        print('[-] Port is closed')
    sock.close()
```

Comment: Is there a newline in the `hosts.txt` file? If there is you may want to check that host.strip() != '' before attempting a connection

Comment: @OluwafemiSule It worked, seems like it was not sending trough what i thought it would. Thank you!